Jest gives me the following in React native: "Jest gives me the following: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"
In my react native app project, i'm trying to run a test on the login page screen, test only the rendering of the elements in it. What i get :
Details:

    C:\Users\Hp\OneDrive\Desktop\testing with jest\testingJest\node_modules\@fortawesome\react-native-fontawesome\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { default as FontAwesomeIcon } from './dist/components/FontAwesomeIcon'
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

       8 |   StyleSheet,
       9 | } from 'react-native';
    > 10 | import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
         | ^
      11 | import {faPhone} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
      12 | import {faEye} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
      13 | import Svg, {Path} from 'react-native-svg';

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
      at Object.require (screens/LoginScreen.js:10:1)
      at Object.require (__tests__/Login.test.tsx:3:1)

And heres the test code Login.test.tsx
import React from 'react';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';

describe('LoginScreen', () => {
  test('renders correctly', () => {
    const {getByTestId, getByPlaceholderText, getByText} = render(
      <LoginScreen />,
    );
    const container = getByTestId('login-container');
    expect(container).toBeTruthy();

    const textConnection = getByText('Connexion');
    expect(textConnection).toBeTruthy();

    const placeTextPhone = getByPlaceholderText('Phone Number');
    expect(placeTextPhone).toBeTruthy();

    const placePassword = getByPlaceholderText('Password');
    expect(placePassword).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

And the jest.config.js :
module.exports = {
   preset: 'react-native',
};

And babel.config.js :
module.exports = {
   presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
};

i run yarn test expecting to receive a test pass

I added a mock for the fontawesome in the test code, and it worked :
jest.mock('@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome', () => ({ FontAwesomeIcon: '', }));

